# Session userdata can't get data with curl

Tags: php, codeigniter, curl

i want to implement CSRF attack and send link code to user. this url functions as change password user.

in this implemetation CSRF attack, hacker send fake url post with `curl` and send parameter 'password' to change password user target.

**code for attack target**

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
                 "password=12345&re_password=12345");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 
                 "http://localhost/onlineshop/change-password/forgot");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
$output = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch);      
echo $output;
```

in function forgot password

```
<?php
function forgot() {
    var_dump($this->ci->session->userdata('user_info'));
}
```

from fake url session user_id = 0, but i check from this url `http://localhost/onlineshop/change-password/forgot` id = 1

why session can't get session from fake url ?

Comment: how you are pushing values to session, can you please put the code?

Comment: $this->ci->session->set_userdata('user_info', $querylogin);

Comment: @MarshallTelaumbanua you cannot use `user's session` variable with `curl`

Comment: @M.Hemant ok. and how to implement fake link with method post without curl?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Curl request can't take session because of its a request over HTTP and session always maintain on the user's system. so, first of all, you have to make strong logic and program to keep that protected, you can't check csrf using Curl. The way you are doing is not a good approach.

You should set a token along with password reset link and check that whenever users click on that to reset the password and make sure it always have expiry.

Comment: i want inplementation CSRF attack before CSRF protection active. but i have problem in query change password. the condition `WHERE` need id user to change password

Comment: Yes, that's why I was saying that your approach is not good. Do one thing create 2 columns in users table recovery_token and recovery_token_date. Store token inside recover_token and token created date inside recovery_token_date.

Comment: After that attach a recover token in URL but not user-id and send that link to a user and whenever a user will click on that URL it should go to user recovery page and over there just check the token and its expiry and then grant permission to recovery password.

Comment: Okay, I understand. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Well maybe there is issue while pushing into your CI Sessions:

```
$arr_user['user_info']['id'] = 2 //any dummy value
// Add user data in session
$this->session->set_userdata($arr_user);
```

Now to check and sure,please debug it by doing `print_r($_SESSION);`

Now on your desired page, try this:

```
print_r($this->session->userdata);
```

OR

```
print_r($this->session->all_userdata());
```

You will get your all values enabled currently.
Also make sure you have session enabled on your page.

In your forget where you are returning the data,

```
<?php

    function forgot() {
        $session_data = $this->ci->session->userdata('user_info');
       echo json_encode($session_data);
    }
```

Comment: i cant problem with push session. in i can get session data user_info. but in fake link get data with curl session is `null`

Comment: Well, then if you are fetching the data from Curl, are you sure the pages or link does return data?

Comment: yes, the link return data if i'am go to link `http://localhost/onlineshop/change-password/forgot`

Comment: curl return data to string `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1)`. `json_encode` not the solution